# Convergence of $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{\sin n (1-\sin n)}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

How I can prove that this sum converges?
I can prove that  $\frac{\sin n}{n}$ converges and  that $(1-\sin n)$ is bounded.

Comment: $1-\sin n$ certainly doesn't tend to $0$....

Comment: yes, it's only bounded

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sin^2 x  = \frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}$$

then, 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin n (1-\sin n)}{n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\sin n}{n} - \frac{\sin^2 n}{n} \right)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\sin n}{n} + \frac{\cos(2n)}{2n}-\frac{1}{2n} \right).$$

But the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin n}{n} $$
and $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{\cos(2n)}{2n} $$ converges by Dirichlet test.
Whereas the series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2n} $$ diverges.
Hence, $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\sin n}{n} + \frac{\cos(2n)}{2n}-\frac{1}{2n} \right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin n (1-\sin n)}{n}.$$ also diverges

Answer (score 3):

The series is divergent. Note that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin n (1-\sin n)}{n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left[ \frac{\sin n}{n} - \frac{\sin^2 n}{n} \right].$$

Now the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin n}{n}$ converges by the Dirichlet test. But the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^2 n}{n}$ diverges to infinity, since for each $k \geqslant 1$ at least one of the numbers $n = 3k-2, 3k-1, 3k$ satisfies $|\sin n| \geqslant \frac{1}{2}$, so

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^2 n}{n} \geqslant \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\frac{1}{4}}{3k} = \infty.$$

Therefore

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left[ \frac{\sin n}{n} - \frac{\sin^2 n}{n} \right] = -\infty.$$

Answer (score 1):

The given series **is not convergent** by [Kronecker's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%27s_lemma), since the partial sums of $\sin(n)(1-\sin(n))$ **are not** bounded. We have $\left|\sum_{n=1}^{N}\sin(n)\right|\leq 2$ but 
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\sin^2(n)\sim \frac{N}{2}. $$